# Can events be passed by reference in Systemverilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

If I call a task and pass an event by reference, it will not be detected inside the task after the event has been triggered:

```
   event e;

   fork
     test_ev(e);
     begin 
        #1ms;
        ->e;
     end
   join

   ...

   task ev(ref event e);
      @(e)
         do_something;    // this will never happen
   endtask
```

Playing around with this test bench: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5YS7, it would seem that some simulators like the `ref event` and some don't. No compile warning is issued, but the `@(..)` statement is never passed.

It seems a valid SystemVerilog use to me, is there a caveat that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to pass an event variable by reference - it is already a reference.

The problem here is that SystemVerilog kludged two constructs into a single keyword. In Verilog, an `event` was simply a valueless variable that you could change with a trigger `->` and wait for it to change like any other variable.

SystemVerilog enhanced the `event` data type to behave more like a class variable. Except an `event` does not need a constructor, any event declaration automatically constructs an event object. This keeps events backward compatible with Verilog. When you make an assignment from one event variable to another event variable, you are copying a handle to an event object. This is the same as copying a class variable - you are only copying the handle, not the object.

So to make your code work, replace `ref` with `input`.

Comment: wow this class behaviour of `event` is unintuitive.. so now I understand why `input` works and it makes sense to use it that way. I'm still curious why it doesn't work when using `ref`? Shouldn't this create a reference inside the task anyway?

Comment: I don't think the LRM is very clear here. Since this is a reference to a reference event, @e could be interpreted as waiting for the reference to change to another event object, not the event trigger itself. Probably should be made an illegal construct.

Answer (score 4):

Passing the event as `task ev(event e)` should also pass it by reference, as it happens with class objects. It doesn't really make sense to pass events by value (i.e. copy it and give the function a new event), since events don't really store data. I'm not sure if this is listed in the LRM explicitly, but IMO it's just common sense.

Tools where your block doesn't get triggered treat events as primitives and pass them by value. I would file support cases for these.

Comment: I agree that it wouldn't make sense in any program to pass events by value. But, at first glance, I would have expected they were treated the same as an int or bit. The issue goes away if declaring the event as `input` to the ask, as @dave_59 suggested, so tool seems to be doing the right thing. Still not sure why it fails with `ref` though